# Shell script to run multiple jar files

Tags: java, unix

I have created three jar files (SSS_Infinite.jar, SSS_Lwindow.jar, SSS_LwindowExe.jar) as part of requirement. Need to design a shell script to run all three in a single one sequentially.

Can you please help on this, i dont find any help for executign multiple jar files in a single shell script.

Regards,
Vidhya C

Comment: Do you know how to run a single jar? 
It seems you are asking to run 3 jars, one after the other. If that is the case, execute each jar one after the other independently

Comment: Can you please help with executing single jar file via shellscript first, I can try and let you updated

Comment: @AloneInTheDark : There is a difference in input parameter to be passed to each jar file so needs to be executed in sequence but there is no dependancy. Can you help me in writing shell script, I cant open vi editor in windows 8 cmd box, any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
x=`ls -l |awk '{print $NF}'|grep '.jar'`

for y in $x; do
java -jar $y
done
```

**EDIT**

The code below will run every jar file inside the directory that you're running.

```
 java -jar *.jar
```

Comment: There is no dependancy between codes, they can execute in sequence one after another. Can you plz provide a basic shell script to trigger jar file in unix

Comment: There is a difference in input parameter to be passed to each jar file so needs to be executed in sequence but there is no dependancy. Can you help me in writing shell script, I cant open vi editor in windows 8 cmd box, any suggestion